# TypeError: Cannot read property 'primaryColor' of undefined - Typescript, Styled Components (tsx)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typeerror, styled-components

I am running a few random react-library tests here and I keep running into the following TypeError: Cannot read property 'primaryColor' of undefined.  The component renders. But I seem to be missing something. I have been scratching my head for hours on this one to no avail as is believe the types have already been set. I have included the relevant code below. Can you help me spot the issue?  A 1000 thank yous in advance for your help.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'primaryColor' of undefined

  22 |         props.isBackgroundPrimary2Color
  23 |           ? "white"
> 24 |           : props.theme.colors.primaryColor}
     |                                ^
  25 |       0%,
  26 |     white 190%
  27 |   );
```

```
    import React from "react";
    
    import styled from "styled-components";
    
    interface PrimaryButtonProps {
      children: string;
      //note boolean props start with is to convey a question
      isBackgroundPrimary2Color?: boolean;
    }
    
    //shortened this section for brevity
    const PrimaryButtonStyles = styled.button<PrimaryButtonProps>`
      background: linear-gradient(
        45deg,
        ${(props) =>
            props.isBackgroundPrimary2Color
              ? "white"
              : props.theme.colors.primaryColor}
          0%,
        white 190%
      );
    `

const PrimaryButton = ({
      isBackgroundPrimary2Color,
    children,
      ...otherProps
    }: PrimaryButtonProps) => {
      return (
        <PrimaryButtonStyles
          isBackgroundPrimary2Color={isBackgroundPrimary2Color}
          {...otherProps}
        >
          {children}
        </PrimaryButtonStyles>
      );
    };
    
    export default PrimaryButton;
```

As per the documentation here is my styled.d.ts file:

```
        import "styled-components";
        
        // extend the default theme using declaration merging theme into styled components
        declare module "styled-components" {
          export interface DefaultTheme {
            fonts: {
              family: string;
              size: {
                standard: string;
              };
              fontColors: {
                primaryDisabledButtonFont: string;
                primaryButton2Font: string;
              };
            };
            colors: {
              background: string;
              primaryColor: string;
            };
          }
        }
```

Here is my theme.tsx file:

```
    
        import React from "react";
        import { DefaultTheme } from "styled-components";
        
        const theme: DefaultTheme = {
          fonts: {
            family: "sans-serif",
            size: {
              standard: "16px",
            },
            fontColors: {
              primaryDisabledButtonFont: "#0000004d",
              primaryButton2Font: "#64E2D3",
            },
          },
          colors: {
            background: "#f8f8f8",
            primaryColor: "#645f43",
          },
        };
        
        export { theme };
        
        And finally the App.tsx file and index.tsx file:
        
        import React, { useState } from "react";
        
        import NavBar from "./components/NavBar/NavBar";
        import Grid from "./layout/Grid";
        import { Footer } from "./components/Footer/Footer";
        import PrimaryButton from "./components/Buttons/PrimaryButton";
        
        function App() {
          return (
            <div>
              <PrimaryButton>Sign Up</PrimaryButton>
            </div>
          );
        }
    
        export default App;
```

and lastly my index.tsx file

```
        import React from "react";
        import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
        import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
        
        // import "./index.css"; removed and moved to globalStyles
        import App from "./App";
        import { theme } from "./styles/theme";
        import GlobalStyle from "./styles/GlobalStyles";
        
        ReactDOM.render(
          <React.StrictMode>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
              <GlobalStyle />
              <App />
            </ThemeProvider>
          </React.StrictMode>,
          document.getElementById("root")
        );
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is `props.theme` defined in your PrimaryButtonProps interface? Right now, it doesn't know about that property's existence despite it being provided via the `ThemeProvider`

Comment: thank you for your response. right now props.theme is not in the interface. I am confused on why that would be required?  Wouldn't it be passed through App in index.tsx?  Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, so based on their docs, it looks like creating a functional component requires importing the interface:
https://styled-components.com/docs/api#caveat-with-function-components

Comment: @Dom thank you, i'll take a look at the caveat,  bit confused on what this ThemeInterface is.  Will have to take a further look but i'll follow the new path.  Much appreciated!

Comment: I am still having some issues event with including ```theme?: DefaultTheme``` in my interface.  Not sure what's up. Driving me bonkers.

Comment: could this be a tsconfig.json issue? should in be adding something to the include?

Answer (score 0):

It's throwing that error because you probably did not add the theme decorator in your `.preview` file. This is how I solved this problem.

I created `decorator.ts file with my theme decorator like this`

```
import React from 'react'
import { DecoratorFn } from '@storybook/react'
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components'
import { lightTheme, darkTheme } from '../styles/theme'
import { GlobalStyle } from '../styles/GlobalStyle'

const withTheme: DecoratorFn = (StoryFn, context) => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={lightTheme}>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <StoryFn />
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

export const globaDecorators = [withTheme]
```

Then inside the `.preview.ts file`, you can export the theme decorator like this

```
export const decorators = globaDecorators
```

This will work. You will have to restart your storybook dev server for it work